# Ruby on Rails - AngularJS add new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

In my Ruby on Rails application i'm trying to add a new record through AngularJS. I'm using this method:

i create a resource called notification:

```
rails g resource notifications title:string body:text
```

and i've populate it:

```
Notification.create!(title: "Test1", body:" Some Text here")
Notification.create!(title: "Test2", body:" Some Text here")
Notification.create!(title: "Test3", body:" Some Text here")
Notification.create!(title: "Test4", body:" Some Text here")
```

i pass all data by Json (located in http://localhost:3000/application/notifications)

i set up now some angular js:

```
app.controller('notificationCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    // array for the notifications
    $scope.notifications = [];

    // method for get the notification
    var retriveNotifications = function(){
        // Console Log
        console.log(' Sto preparando le notifiche ');
        // trying to get to the notification page
        $http.get('/application/notifications').success(
            // getting the notifications
            function(items){
                $scope.notifications = items;
            }); 
    };

    //add a notification
    $scope.updateNotifications = function(title, body){
         var item = {title: title , body: body}

        $http.post('/application/notifications', item);
    }


    retriveNotifications();


}])
```

this is my html file:

```
<form ng-submit="updateNotification()">
    <input ng-model="notificationName" placeholder="Title of the notification">
    <input ng-model="notificationText" placeholder="Body of notification">
    <input type="submit" value="Send"> 
</form>
<ul ng-repeat="notification in notifications">
    <li>
        <h4>{{notification.title}}</h4>
        <p>{{notification.body}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm a beginner of Angular JS and i know that the function updateNotifications is wrong. How i can insert (in the Notification database) a new record with Angular JS?

Thanks for the help

Comment: In the form, you call `updateNotification()`, but in the controller the method is named `updateNotifications`. Not sure if that's the only problem, but the first thing that popped out to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there is a type in your update notification function

in your html file it is updateNotification();

in your js file it is updateNotifications also remove title and body params from the function as you are not declaring them in your html

to add a new record simple use push method to your array

```
     app.controller('notificationCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

// array for the notifications
    $scope.notifications = [];

   $scope.newItem ={};

// method for get the notification
    var retriveNotifications = function(){
    // Console Log
     console.log(' Sto preparando le notifiche ');
    // trying to get to the notification page
    $http.get('/application/notifications').success(
        // getting the notifications
        function(items){
            $scope.notifications = items;
        }); 
};
  $scope.updateNotifications = function(){
      var title = $scope.notificationName;
      var body = $scope.notificationText;
     var newItem = {title: title , body: body}

    $http.post('/application/notifications', newItem);
    //push your new item to notification array of records 
    $scope.notifications.push(newItem);
     $scope.newItem = {};
    }

    retriveNotifications();


 }])
```

I highly recommend this screen cast for you to begin using rails with angularjs

[Angularjs and rails (railscasts.com](http://railscasts.com/episodes/405-angularjs)